# Change admin module title joomla

Tags: joomla

When I installed the module that I developed and in the module manager screen of the backend I can see the title like this.

Module Manager: Module mod_examplemodule

So I want to change it into something like this. Module Manager: Module Example Module

I have developed few Joomla modules but so far I didn't realize how to do this.

Your help on this would really appreciated.

Thank you.

Im using Joomla 2.5.8. I have just added the screen shot. Perhaps it would be more helpful[image].

Comment: You working with which Joomla version?

Comment: Can you please add the screenshot of admin panel

Comment: What value do you have inbetween the <name> tags in the XML?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. In-between name tags I have the value "WWD Contact Module". Exactly like this "<name>WWD Contact Module</name>".Hope this is correct.

Comment: Finally I have find the solution. Its not about the XML file I guess. I have added MOD_WWDCONTACT="WWD Contact" to the language file (Ex. en-GB.mod_sample.ini) while XML file remain as it is. Thats works perfectly. Thank you very much all of you guys who helped me through this. :)

Answer (score 3):

In my modules I use:

```
<name>Module Title</name>
<description>MOD_MODULE_TITLE_XML_DESCRIPTION</description>
```

I then add an entry in the language file for the description.  This normally covers my needs

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is how my name and description tags in the XML looks like.<name>WWD Contact Module</name><description>Conatct Module</description> I have checked the data base table (#__extensions) and "name" column having the value of "WWD Contact Module". But "element" column having the value of "mod_wwdcontact". I think this is the value cause me this problem. Please take a look on my screen shot in the question and it will explain the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this:

1. You can change name tag in mod_examplemodule.xml file and install again

   OR
2. If you have database access then in  [prefix]_modules table find the record of this module and change the name field as per your requirement

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I do have database access but I prefer the way of doing it through installation. Can you please explain bit more what is the exact tag that I should change.

Comment: it is name tag in the xml file